# how to a make the camera fade off as fog rather than straight clipping?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

My render image current has a hard clip. I can extend the cameras view to 100,000 and it still clips. what am I doing wrong

[image: clipping]

[image: sorry about the Minecraft example but this is the render effect I'm after]

Comment: Hello :). You can try the [Mist Pass](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/world_settings.html#mist-pass) in World settings.

Comment: As Jachym said, you can use the mist pass, but with a high "Start" value, so that it doesn't apply to all the scene, just the edges.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a go at that!